# Extract text only from htmlentities type string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML encoded string (encoded by htmlentities PHP function):

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;u style=&quot;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Comic Sans MS&quot;&gt;adsasdasdasdasdas&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I need to extract and display the text only from this string using JavaScript. I have tried `toString`, `unescape` function and some other function but these functions were not very helpful for me.

I a trying to append the text only from this string on the success function of AJAX call.

This technique is not working for me : `http://jsfiddle.net/k65s3/`

Comment: <?php echo html_entity_decode("&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;u style=&quot;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Comic Sans MS&quot;&gt;adsasdasdasdasdas&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"); ?>

Comment: I need this is JavaScript not in PHP :)